# Object is not callable - Thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I trying to build a window to control my program, BUT when I execute it:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python3.8\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "D:\python3.8\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: 'MainWindow' object is not callable
```

I'm not sure if it's a syntax error or something else...

CODE:

```
class MainWindow:
    def quit(self)->'mine':
        windows.destroy()
        exit()
    def start(self):
        self.frame = tk.Frame(windows)
        self.frame.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)
        self.button = tk.Button(self.frame, text='quit', fg='red', command=quit)
        self.button.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
        windows.mainloop()
t = threading.Thread(target = MainWindow())
t.start()
```

IDE:VS Code

Comment: You can't call classes in a thread. You can call the class'es function in a thread. First create an object of your class then call the start function.  t = threading.Thread(target = obj.start())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have an **init** function, you are currently not calling the object constructor, so you dont have an actual object. Try adding the **init** function.

```
class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        self.start()
    def quit(self)->'mine':
        windows.destroy()
        exit()
    def start(self):
        self.frame = tk.Frame(windows)
        self.frame.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)
        self.button = tk.Button(self.frame, text='quit', fg='red', command=quit)
        self.button.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
        windows.mainloop()
t = threading.Thread(target = MainWindow())
t.start()
```